# Loop multiple files from input, save each file readAsDataURL data to array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader

I need your help with following problem:

1. I have HTML input which supports multiple files;
2. I upload let's say 5 files;
3. Each file is processed: it is readAsDataURL by FileReader and data of file is saved to object(there will be other params saved too, that is why object), which is pushed to array.
4. After I run flow I described, length of final array is NOT changed.

I believe problem is in async behaviour, but I cannot understand how should I change code to make it work, that is why I ask you for a help. Please find code below:

```
    var controls = document.getElementById('controls');

    function processUploadedFilesData(files) {
      if (!files[0]) {
        return;
      };

      var uploads = [];

      for (var i = 0, length = files.length; i < length; i++) {
        (function(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          //I need object, as other params will be saved too in future; 
          var newFile = {};
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            newFile.data = e.target.result;
            uploads.push(newFile);
          }
        })(files[i]);
      }
      return uploads;
    }

    controls.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      var uploadedFilesOfUser = processUploadedFilesData(e.target.files);
      alert(uploadedFilesOfUser.length);
    });
```

Codepen example - https://codepen.io/yodeco/pen/xWevRy